# PHP cannot connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am reading the head first book on PHP and MySQL. Just started chapter 2 where they connect to database. But my script doesn't do anything. I get no error from the "or die" even when I purposefully enter the incorrect connection string, and the query doesn't insert. I am running Ubuntu server 14 with PHP  5.6.4 and MySQL 5.6.24 on a VM on my Mac.

I can connect remotely with MySQL workbench and execute the query which is successful.

Here is the my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Aliens Abducted Me - Report an abduction</title>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Aliens Abducted Me - Report an abduction</h2>
<?php

$name = $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname'];
$when_it_happened = $_POST['whenithappened'];
$how_long = $_POST['howlong'];
$how_many = $_POST['howmany'];
$alien_description = $_POST['aliendescription'];
$what_they_did = $_POST['whattheydid'];
$fang_spotted = $_POST['fangspotted'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$other = $_POST['other'];

echo 'Thanks for submitting the form ' . $name . '<br />';
echo 'You were abducted ' . $when_it_happened;
echo ' and were gone for ' . $how_long . '<br />';
echo 'You saw ' . $how_many . ' of them' . '<br />';
echo 'Describe them: ' . $alien_description . '<br />';
echo 'What the did: ' . $what_they_did . '<br />';
echo 'Was Fang there? ' . $fang_spotted . '<br />';
echo 'Your email address is ' . $email . '<br />';
echo 'Additional information: ' . $other;

$dbc = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'password', 'aliendatabase')
or die('Error connecting to server');


$query = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (first_name, last_name, " .
    "when_it_happened, how_long, how_many, alien_description, " .
    "what_they_did, fang_spotted, other, email)" .
    "VALUES ('Sally', 'Jones', '3 days ago', '1 day', 'four', " .
    "'green with 6 tenticles', 'We talked and played with a dog', " .
    "'yes', 'I may have seen your dog', 'sally@gregs-list.net')";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
or die ('Error querying DB');

mysqli_close($dbc);


?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried changing the host to localhost, ip address, loopback address all with and without the port number. But what the most frustrating thing is that I get no errors. Even when I should be.

I have even read up on different ways to create the connect/error commands using "if" i.e.

```
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

no difference. What is going wrong?

Comment: this does not help you mysql_error its mysqli_error($dbc) and apply it to your query

Comment: Hi Fred,thanks for the response. I have tried that, was just describing what i have tried. Doesn't work.

Comment: default password for root user in mysql is empty "" try that see if it works. 

`$dbc = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'aliendatabase')`

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 $dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password",'aliendatabase');

if(!$dbc)
{
   echo "cannot connet to the server";
}
$q = "Your insert query here";
$query=mysqli_query($dbc, $q)
 or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc));
 mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, i appreciate it. I discovered what the issue is. The errors not displaying was thanks to the errors not being setup in my php.ini (display_errors=off, needs to be changed to on). then i got this error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()" and this was because mysqli extension was not installed. Can be checked with php -m | grep on linux, if returns nothing then mysqli is not installed. install php5-mysqlnd and restart apache. Then fixed thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for getting back to me, i appreciate it. I discovered what the issue is. The errors not displaying was thanks to the errors not being setup in my php.ini (display_errors=off, needs to be changed to on). then i got this error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()" and this was because mysqli extension was not installed. Can be checked with php -m | grep on linux, if returns nothing then mysqli is not installed. install php5-mysqlnd and restart apache. Then fixed thanks for all the help.